# Pass parameters to subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

Are there any way to make this query less ugly? I want to avoid code duplication and I don't want to create stored procedure or function for such little piece of code

```
select 
    CB.CompanyName as ClientName,
    Sum30 = (
                select 
                    sum(TotalAmount) as sum30 
                from 
                    InvoiceBrowse 
                where 
                    DATEDIFF(day, CreatedOn, @now) > @days_limit AND 
                    DATEDIFF(day, CreatedOn, @now) <= 30 AND 
                    ClientCompanyName = IB.ClientCompanyName
            ),
    Sum60 = (
                select 
                    sum(TotalAmount) as sum30 
                from 
                    InvoiceBrowse 
                where 
                    DATEDIFF(day, CreatedOn, @now) > @days_limit AND 
                    DATEDIFF(day, CreatedOn, @now) <= 60 AND 
                    ClientCompanyName = IB.ClientCompanyName
            ),
    Sum90 = (
                select 
                    sum(TotalAmount) as sum30 
                from 
                    InvoiceBrowse 
                where 
                    DATEDIFF(day, CreatedOn, @now) > @days_limit AND 
                    DATEDIFF(day, CreatedOn, @now) <= 90 AND 
                    ClientCompanyName = IB.ClientCompanyName
            )
from  
    InvoiceBrowse IB
```

Some explanation: I have table with invoices and want to calculate sum of invoices for each company for 30\60\90 days.

Comment: The alternatives I can think of are also "ugly". Function, view, or CTE, but for this little piece it likely doesn't do much  =)

Comment: You can use a scalar function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx

Comment: tsql tag was not redundant.  The guideline is to use tsql.

Comment: Make no sense.  CB is not defined and clearly InvoiceBrowse repeats company name.

Comment: @Paparazzi Actually it is not correct query, I just tried to show the idea.

Comment: Why don't you show the idea with a valid query?  And put a little effort into formatting.

Comment: @Paparazzi I supposed it was enough for understanding otherwise I can just clarify it.

Comment: In looking at some of your other questions this is your standard level of effort.  And a very low acceptance rate.

Comment: @Paparazzi You can clarify the question if you think that I didn't describe it well. You can skip the question if you think that it is not cost your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like you're missing a table in your example.. but something like this might work.

```
SELECT  ClientCompanyName AS ClientName,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,CreatedOn,@now) <= 30 THEN TotalAmount END) AS Sum30,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,CreatedOn,@now) <= 60 THEN TotalAmount END) AS Sum60,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,CreatedOn,@now) <= 90 THEN TotalAmount END) AS Sum90
FROM    InvoiceBrowse
WHERE   CreatedOn < DATEADD(DAY, -@days_limit, @now)
GROUP BY ClientCompanyName
```